# Create a mapper function in python

Tags: python, mapreduce

Create a mapper that reads in the lines of  counts the words in each line and then returns the (key,value) pairs for those word counts.

I don't know what to write inside this function

```
 def file_mapper(filename)
```

Comment: What kind of file are you reading?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def file_mapper(filename):
    with open(filename+'.txt','r') as file:
        return {c:len(e.split(' ')) for c,e in enumerate(file.read().split("\n"))}
```

Try this. Line numbering starts at zero